# NextAuth.js - How to use redirect and callbackUrl simultaneously in signIn()

Tags: next-auth

Hello I am new to NextAuth.js, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to disable redirect and still use callbackUrl at the same time within the signIn() function.

I want to disable redirect to allow an alert component to pop up for invalid credentials. I also want to use the callbackUrl function when I successfully login to route the user to the dashboard.

```
function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    // Set the loading state to true while the sign-in process is in progress.
    setIsLoading(true);

    // Use the signIn function to attempt to sign in with provided credentials.
    signIn("credentials", {
        // Disable automatic redirection
        redirect: false,
        callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
        username: values.username,
        password: values.password,
    }).then((response) => {
        // Check if the sign-in response contains an error.
        if (response?.error) {
            // Display an alert to indicate that sign-in failed.
            setShowAlert(true);

            // Automatically hide the alert after 5 seconds.
            setTimeout(() => {
                setShowAlert(false);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle unexpected errors that occur during the sign-in process.
        console.error("An unexpected error happened:", error);
    }).finally(() => {
        // Set the loading state to false when the promise is resolved or rejected.
        setIsLoading(false);
    });
}
```

I tried to manually route using useRouter() from 'next/router' but it did not work for me.

```
function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
        setIsLoading(true);
        signIn("credentials", {
            redirect: false,
            username: values.username,
            password: values.password,
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response?.error) {
                setShowAlert(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setShowAlert(false);
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                const router = useRouter();      ++++   <-- manually use router
                router.push("/dashboard")        ++++
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("An unexpected error happened:", error);
        }).finally(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to achieve both disabling the redirect and using callbackUrl for successful logins. Thank you!

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Thank you for the response. I just tried to move the useRouter() to the scope of onSubmit() and event the client component itself but unfortunately I still get errors. When placing inside the scope of onSubmit(), I get the error "Invalid hook call.". When I place it within the scope of the entire component, I get the error "NextRouter was not mounted". This is a bit confusing for me because shouldn't I get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I placed the hook at the top level of the component but used useRouter() from 'next/navigation' instead of 'next/router'. This works for me.